# Как спозиционировать абсолютно спозиционированный элемент относительно браузера, если он находится в блоке с относительным позиционированием?

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Как спозиционировать абсолютно спозиционированный элемент относительно браузера, если он находится в блоке с относительным позиционированием, при этом не отменяя у родителя относительное позиционирование?
Пример: в сетке bootstrap каждая колонка (col-*) имеет position: relative, а у меня в этой колонке есть элемент, который я хочу спозиционировать относительно окна браузера, но он позиционируется относительно колонки bootstrap.
Есть ли какое-то решение для этого? Может можно задавать приоритет позиционирования или что-то в этом роде, т.к. не хочется трогать лишний раз саму сетку bootstrap.

Comment: А ответы типа `никак` не принимаются? Надо обязательно придумать новое извращение с применением какой-то штуки не по назначению?

Comment: Владимир, можете рассказать задачу, которую хотите решить таким образом? Возможно, у неё есть другое решение. Например, переместить элемент из колонки в ряд или в контейнер, у которых нет относительного позиционирования.

Answer (score 2):

Если этот элемент должен быть спозиционирован абсолютно относительно окна браузера, то нет никакого смысла размещать его в колонке bootstrap. Разместите ваш элемент сразу после body.